# copying a string to another string in C

Tags: c

```
char *stringcopywithpointer( const char *source)
{
   int ii = 0;
   int len = strlen(source) +1;
   char *dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);

   while(*source != '\0')
   {   
      // dest[ii++] = *source++;
         *dest++ = *source++;
   }

   // dest[ii] = '\0';
    *dest = '\0';
    printf("\n copied string = %s", dest1);
    return dest;
}
```

I want to copy source string to destination string.
The above api is returning null.
If I use array of character (this I have commented) then this api works to me.

Please help me to understand the difference between

```
dest[ii++] = *source++
```

and

```
*dest++ = *source++;
```

Comment: I realize it's a minor point, but the function name `stringcopywithpointer()` begins with `str`, so it's in a space reserved for the implementation. The function should be renamed.

Comment: Your comment was not minor to me, I was unaware of that. Maybe, even a bit more nitpicking: names beginning with `str` are only reserved if the forth letter is lowercase (which is the case for `stringcopywithpointer`).

Answer (score 8):

You're incrementing `dest` during the `while` loop.  You need to keep hold of a pointer to the start of the buffer to return from the function.

```
char *stringcopywithpointer( const char *source)
{
    int ii = 0;
    int len = strlen(source);
    char *copy = malloc(len+1);
    char* dest = copy;

    while(*source != '\0')
    {   
        *dest++ = *source++;
    }

    *dest = '\0';
    printf("\n copied string = %s", copy);
    return copy;
}
```

Note that you could save some code by using [strcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)

```
char *stringcopywithpointer( const char *source)
{
    int len = strlen(source);
    char *copy = malloc(len+1);
    strcpy(copy, source);
    return copy;
}
```

and you could reduce this to a single line if you have access to the non-standard [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)

```
char *stringcopywithpointer( const char *source)
{
    return strdup(source);
}
```

Comment: that what he did in his code, the allocated memory is `int len = strlen(source) +1; so the null char is counted`

Comment: @MOHAMED Yep, thanks, I only noticed that when I added the updated version of the function.

Comment: maybe `return dest-len+1` is the solution to his proble

Comment: @MOHAMED That would work but its not the clearest code and seems prone to bugs.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion:

Avoid allocate memory in called function, better allot memory before calling a function

```
char *dest = ( char* ) malloc( sizeof( char ) * len ); // doesn't looks great
```

Irrespective of the machine, `sizeof( char )` is always 1 byte. Less redundant is `sizeof( char ) * len`. Optimal would be `malloc( sizeof( source ) )`.

Pointers and arrays are related
You can either use

```
dest[i] = src[i]; 
*dst++ = *src++;
```

or

```
// assuming dst memory allocate by caller 
while ( *dst++ = *src++);
```

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
printf("\n copied string = %s", dest1);
```

should be

```
printf("\n copied string = %s", dest);
```

This could be a typo

2)

You can change:

```
while(*source != '\0')
{   
    *dest++ = *source++;
}
```

by

```
while(*dest++ = *source++);
```

3)

Concerning difference between `dest[ii++] = *source++` and `*dest++ = *source++;`

There is no difference and should work if `dest` is defined in this way

```
char *dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
```

If your array is define in this way:

```
char dest[len];
```

Then there is difference

Comment: This wouldn't matter as he is doing `dest++` in while loop which will make `dest` point to last character.

Answer (score 1):

You should not return an allocated string. This can easily lead to a memory leak.

Instead you should consider passing allocated memory into your function to copy it.
You can use your return value to return an error if anything went wrong.

This would change your signature to.

```
int stringcopywithpointer( char * dest, const char *source)
```

to make your code a little bit more versitile you could implement vargs and your signature would be:

```
int stringcopywithpointerf( char * dest, const * format, ... );
```

This is actually the already existing function sprintf.

```
int sprintf( char * dest, const * format, ... );
```

There are also secure variants of the function available and premade. You may want to consider using one of those.

If this is homework related take a look at this function:

```
char * myscpy(const char * SRC){
    size_t size = strlen( SRC ) + 1 ;
    char * START;
    char * DST = ( char * ) malloc( size );
    START = DST;
    do
    {
        *DST = *SRC;
        DST++;
        SRC++;
    }while( *SRC != 0 );
    *DST = *SRC;
    return START;
}
```

You likely want to add errorchecks to it like you had them in place (malloc etc.) in your original post.

---

"Please help me to understand the difference between dest[i++] and *dest++"

dest[i++] does not increment the pointer but the index to the pointer.
*dest++ increments the pointer after its original contendt was accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Add `char *dest1 = dest;` right after malloc and then return dest1 and that will work.

Other possible change: replace while loop with post-condition loop (i.e. copy the zero byte first, then check if it was the end).

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to add this line

```
char *stringcopywithpointer( const char *source)
{
   int ii = 0;
   int len = strlen(source) +1;
   char *ptr = NULL;
   char *dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);

   /**  No Error Checking for malloc is a strict no no **/
   if(dest == NULL)  
       return NULL;     

   /** hold the dest adress in ptr as we are incrementing dest **/
   ptr = dest;

   while(*source != '\0')
   {   
      // dest[ii++] = *source++;
         *dest++ = *source++;
   }

   // dest[ii] = '\0';

    *dest = '\0';

  //printf("\n copied string = %s", dest1); ??

  printf("\n copied string = %s", ptr); // ptr will have our copied String

   /** so return ptr not dest **/
    return ptr;

}
```