# How to assign characters of a string to a new string in C

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to make my char `pWR` taking the value of the first 6 characters of char `pW` but I am getting the following error:

```
incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char [6]'
pWR = pW[1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

This is part of my code:

```
char pWR[6];
char pW[30];

pWR = pW[1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: This is not even valid C syntax!!!

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<6; ++i) pWr[i] = pW[i];`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: C does not have an array slicing syntax or whole-array assignment.  You can assign elements one-by-one, perhaps using a loop, or you can copy a whole block of elements via `memcpy` or similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [copying a string to another string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540270/copying-a-string-to-another-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the library function `strncpy` to achieve your objective:

```
char pWR[6]; 
char pW[30] = "abcdefghij";
strncpy(pWR, pW, 6);
```

However, if you are planning to treat pWR as a string, make sure you allow for the null terminator character to mark the end of the string.

The other alternate as suggested by a few commenters is to use `memcpy` function.

```
char pWR[6]; 
char pW[30] = "abcdefghij";
memcpy(pWR, pW, 6);
```

Comment: `strncpy()` is unsafe for this purpose if the original array may contain null bytes.  To copy an exact number of characters, regardless of what they are, `memcpy()` is a better choice.

Comment: Maybe `memcpy` is better in this case since 0 could be legit value, judging by the description example

Comment: Hi VHS, - thank you, this solution worked perfectly and was a simple fix. Just out of interest, if i wanted to take lets say the 1st, 3rd, 8th and 12th character from pW and make pWR these characters could i do that using your solution?

Comment: @lelekes, for that, you will have to run the good old `for` loop and copy the required elements from the source array to the destination array.

Comment: @VHS - Final question, if i wanted just one number from the string e.g the 4th number and no other numbers what would the code for that be? (P.S. thank you for all the help)

Comment: @lelekes, it should be very simple. `pW[0]=pWR[4];`